# authenticate from other table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have **3 types of users** in the application as  below:

```
 1. Super Admin
 2. Normal User
 3. Staff
```

I did set up for the Super Admin but want to set Login System for the "Staff" user. I created one folder name as `Staff` in Controllers folder `/var/www/html/projecy_name/app/Http/Controllers` and created one Controller with name `SessionsController.php`, here is the content in that file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Staff;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Staff;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except'=>'destroy']);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('staffsession.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        echo request("email");
        $test = auth()->attempt(request(['email','password']));
        dd($test);
        if(!auth()->attempt(request(['email','password'])))
        {
            Request()->session()->flash('error_msg', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Please check your credentials and try again.'
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->home();
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->home();
    }
}
?>
```

> In store() function, it is by default going to check in `admins`
>   table, but I want that it must be check in my `tbl_staff` table.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a new guard and provider in the `\config\auth.php` file.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'staff',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'tbl_staff',
    ],
],
```

After that you need to create a new Guard instance with the new provider. It will use the new table for authentification.

Place a `guard()` method into your login controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('staff');
}
```

**Update:**

You have to use your methods differently, so that it works. Use the `guard()` method instead of the `auth()` method because it uses the default guard. See:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Staff;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Staff;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except'=>'destroy']);
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('staff');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('staffsession.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        if(!$this->guard()->attempt(request(['email','password'])))
        {
            Request()->session()->flash('error_msg', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Please check your credentials and try again.'
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->home();
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->home();
    }
}
```

Comment: let me check for with solution

Comment: still it is checking in default table

Comment: @PathikVejani If it works for you please let others know by accepting the answer or upvote. Thanks!