# Authentication from custom user table

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I got a project where I will have two login interfaces, one for Employees and the other one for external people.

The login for employees works like a charm since they are stored in the standard users table provided by laravel.

Right now I am trying to get to work that external accounts get logged in, the registration works and all their user data is stored inside the "portal_users" database, but the login doesn't work. It seems like that it tries to use the standard users database for verification.

Is there a way to make it check a specific database?

```
public function store(Request $request) {


        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);


        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)) {
            return back()->with('status', 'Falsche Login Daten');
        }


        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

This is my function for the users table login process.

And is it possible to give the default user table different roles within or should I create a new auth for each role?

Comment: Have a read through [this tutorial](https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel-multiple-authentication-system-using-different-models)

Comment: I think It is a duplicate title and you are looking for this [authenticate from another table in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711132/authenticate-from-other-table-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: you should learn  guard and provider before implementing